# titlecap – don't capitalize hyphenated "to"

Tags: titlecaps

I'm desperately trying to make `\titlecap` printing *sequence-to-sequence* as *Sequence-to-Sequence*.

However, adding the word "to" to the lower-cased word list (i.e., `\Addlcwords`) does not seem to be enough, the exceptions defined seem to be ignored for hyphenated words – leading to *Sequence-To-Sequence*.

Are there any options available to achieve the aforementioned result?

**MVE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{to}
\begin{document}
    \titlecap{sequence-to-sequence}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked to see why this behaves this way (see **ADDENDUM**).  One would have hoped that adding it to the lower-case list should be sufficient (I haven't looked at the code in a while).  In the meantime...how to override such behavior?

Normally, you would enclose the "to" in `\textnc{to}`, meaning "no change", which overrides the capitalizing imperative inside a `\titlecap` and does nothing outside of it.  However, in your particular example, the word `sequence-to-sequence` is the first word of the argument, which is treated specially (it gets capitalized even if it is in the lower-case list.

So, you need a different approach...See p.3 of the docs: "To prevent a word from being titled (to force it into lower case), it can be immediately preceded by a `\relax`.  In this way, the `\relax` is titled, rather than the following word.  This method can be used to for one-time exceptions to titling,or to overcome the curly-brace problem described above, as in `\{\relax if\}`."

The 1st line shows it without the hyphens.  The 2nd line is the case presented by the OP, with the `\relax` override.  The 3rd is how to do it when the word is not part of the first word of the argument.  The last shows `\textnc` working outside of `\titlecap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{to}
\begin{document}
\titlecap{sequence to sequence}% WITHOUT HYPHENS WORKS AS EXPECTED

\titlecap{sequence-\relax to-sequence}% PREPEND \relax FOR SPECIAL CASE EXCEPTIONS

\titlecap{a sequence-\textnc{to}-sequence}% ENCLOSE WITH \textnc

          a sequence-\textnc{to}-sequence
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Well, it turns out that, while the code can trigger a capitalization following connecting symbols such as `[`, `(`, `-`, etc. (which is what it was doing that you did not like), the only way to use the lower-case word list to prevent capitalization of the `-to-` in your example (in theory, more later) is if you defined a lowercase word as `sequencetosequence`.  But this also does not give what you desire, because it would prevent the `s` letters from being capitalized, along with the `to`.

This odd behavior occurs because the method used by the package is to screen out (ignore) the symbol characters such as `(`, `[`, etc. as part of the lower-case word search.

There is an added complication though and that is that I discover that the hyphen `-` in particular, is not screened out like the other symbols.  I will have to look more closely to decide if I had a valid reason for making that exception.

I can say that, if one wanted to treat the hyphen as it does parens, brackets, etc., it could be done this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\makeatletter
% THESE ARE THE PUNCTUATION MARKS SCREENED OUT FOR 
% LOWER CASE WORD SEARCH
\renewcommand\kill@punct{%
\catcode`-=9 %
\catcode`.=9 %
\catcode`,=9 %
\catcode`:=9 %
\catcode`;=9 %
\catcode`(=9 %
\catcode`)=9 %
\catcode`[=9 %
\catcode`]=9 %
\catcode`?=9 %
\catcode`!=9 %
\catcode``=9 %
\catcode`'=9 %
}

\renewcommand\restore@punct{%
\catcode`-=12 %
\catcode`.=12 %
\catcode`,=12 %
\catcode`:=12 %
\catcode`;=12 %
\catcode`(=12 %
\catcode`)=12 %
\catcode`[=12 %
\catcode`]=12 %
\catcode`?=12 %
\catcode`!=12 %
\catcode``=12 %
\catcode`'=12 %
}
\makeatother
\Addlcwords{sequencetosequence}
\begin{document}
\titlecap[x]{sequence-to-sequence}
\end{document}
```

However, as I noted above, this is also not the desired result because suppression of the `s` capitalization occurs, too

[image]

What you seek will be determined by whether I can perform a new lower-case word search following the non-alphabetic symbols.  I'm guessing I already tried unsuccessfully to do that during the package design.  However, if a solution presents itself, I will update the package.